# How to phrase a request for feedback / support from management?

Tags: project-management, communication

I'm in my first development job out of college and have been handed a (solo) project that is completely outside the range of my skills/experience both in terms of the technologies being used and the sheer scope of the thing.

I've spent the last 6 months or so basically completely retraining myself and then starting to do the thing, and although I did very well at college and I *think* that I'm on track for delivery, I've had zero feedback on what I've been doing and I'm suddenly starting to feel very much out of my depth.

My direct supervisor, while a nice guy and I think a competent coder, doesn't have the best communication skills and basically told me to "read a book" when I asked him for a bit of guidance, which is not really what I was hoping for!

Am I just being unrealistic about the amount of support I can expect as a junior developer? It seems to me that ignoring the issue and ploughing ahead runs the risk of a failed project which is to no-ones benefit. I could take my request for guidance a step higher to the head of development, but I don't want to sound like I'm saying I can't do the job nor do I want to make my supervisor look bad.

Can anyone suggest a good approach for saying "help!" without making myself or my supervisor look bad?

Comment: Are you looking to a programmatic solution to this problem? If not, visit programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a great question, and I think a fairly common situation. Basically, I think what you're asking for is guidance on how to communicate with your boss, and the other people in your organization.

This might be a good time to look into the [scrum framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrum_%28development%29), and take from it what seems applicable to your environment.

In particular, you mention that you might be in over your head. Or, there is an (implicit) expectation that you'll need to finish this project "tomorrow," when you really don't know how long it will take.

I suggest starting with a list. Write down everything you need to do. Include non-coding activities, like "research technology X for doing Y," and give each task a basic time estimate like "1" for short, "2" for medium, "3" for long. Then put the things in an order that you think makes sense.

Then meet with your boss, once a week, for like 20 minutes, to discuss what you did, and what you're going to do next week. Out of this discussion, you'll both see what's going on, and adjust expectations (and the list) accordingly. When conflicts of expectation come up, talk it out.

Regarding the amount of support to expect as a junior developer, this really depends on your organization, and your supervisor's opinion. As software engineering is still a relatively young profession, there isn't much in the way of industry-standard mentoring programs.

I suggest trying the list + meeting thing for a couple months, and observe how your opinion of the support situation changes. Then, go to a large conference as soon as possible; spend the money if you need to. You'll see who is struggling with similar situations, and also who is not, and you'll create your own, more-informed model of "how the industry is supposed to work."

Regarding a good approach to communicating, I (seriously) suggest [The Seven Principles for Making Marriage Work](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0609805797) by John Gottman, which has a lot of examples of what works and doesn't work when communicating with people.

Comment: Also, yeah, this question should be on a different board, but even the programmers board discourages these questions; I think it's an important question, so I wrote my answer here.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Just to know that this is a fairly common situation is a weight off, I'll look into those links you posted too. Feeling a little less anxious having read your reply, obviously I'm not alone in feeling a bit lost in my first position!